# Solve a system of set equations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A_i, B_i$,$i\in \{1,2,3\}$ be non-empty sets. Solve a system of set equations $A_i \cap X=B_i$, $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

So far the only thing I can tell is the obvious fact that $B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3\subseteq X$. Does there even exist an explicit solution for this system?

Comment: Which ones are you solving for?

Comment: @RandomGuy for $X$.

Comment: @hff1 isn't $A_i,B_i$ constant (prev comment) I think you meant add an element to X that's not A

Comment: @RandomGuy Yes, you are right. My wording is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @hff1 is there nothing else I can do other than discuss the existence and uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a general solution to that system. Let us consider this counterexample: $A_1 = A_2 = A_3 = \{1,2,3\}$, with $B_1=\{1\}$, $B_2=\{2\}$, and $B_3=\{3\}$. It becomes clear that $A_i \cap X = \{1, 2, 3\} \cap X$, for all $i$, cannot be simulteaneously $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$.

However, the system might have solutions in certain scenarios. For instance, it is then trivial to show that $X = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3$ is a solution when $A_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$ holds.